# PHP 7 upgrade and errors that came along

Tags: php

I just moved to Digital Ocean (PHP 7.0) and im making a global.php file to pass the admin id that is logged and the admins information. I have ran into an error. I don't know if this is the new php version because i was using PHP 5.6 then i moved here to use 7 and have no cpanel to learn linux commands. Below is my code:

*header.php includes global.php below the mysql.php which connects to the db if you think i forgot to add that, it is included.

```
<?php

$adminid = $_SESSION['adminid'];
$adminGet = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE id  = '$adminid'");
$adminFetch = $adminGet->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);

$admin_first = $adminFetch['first_name'];
```

$admin_first is not reporting firstname. This table does indeed exist and does have admin id 1 which is the session id that is in use (i checked by echoing $_SESION['adminid']

Admins table: http://prntscr.com/fohwtc

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error_log is being reported @kjones

Comment: Is `$adminFetch['first_name']` set? Is it an empty string? Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ` in your index.php just to be sure you're not causing any errors or warnings? PHP 7 handles errors a bit differently.

Comment: What do you mean @Goose

Comment: What is returned by `var_dump($adminFetch);`?

Comment: @JarrodEstepp do you understand `isset()`?

Comment: var_dump returned NULL @kjones

Comment: $goose yea i do understand isset()

Comment: error.log is empty btw

Comment: What is the var_dump of `$conn`? Have you tried doing `echo "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE id  = '$adminid'";` and running that directly in the database.

Comment: Let me run that in the dB

Comment: I ran it in DB and it brought up the query. Also, i tired using Mysqli Prepared Statement and it made it work but i don't like using Prepared Statements when i don't have to.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MYSQLI_ASSOC` instead of `MYSQL_ASSOC`? `mysql_*` doesn't mix with `mysqli_*`

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare).

Comment: I will try Mysqli_assoc

Comment: Qirel is right I think, MYSQL extension was deprecated in modern 5.x php and removed in PHP 7

Comment: I am using MySQLi Prepared satements where users input info to db. Fetching data that users don't touch is waste of lines of code for prepared statements. @Qirel

Comment: @Goose Not only that (meaning the constant `MYSQL_ASSOC` should be removed too), but APIs don't mix/interchange.

Comment: Uhm, no... @JarrodEstepp - it's not waste of time. You should prepare **any** query that use any sort of variable. The time it takes to prepare versus a regular query is minimal difference.

Comment: Yea. MYSQL was removed. I changed MYSQL to MYSQLI and it worked perfectly! Thank you for your help! Now i can start on my project! Really appreciated!

Comment: @JarrodEstepp glad you got it working. I understand you probably don't believe `$adminid` needs the security of prepared statements because it is not a direct user input, but it's far more difficult to understand the full security implications of every variable every time you make a change than it is to just use best security practices. You should also use a framework so it takes care of all this and more under the hood. You should also trust best practices until you are an expert in the field.